# SQL connection string into function

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to put a connection string into a function for database connection:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'Server=trve-tl'
                      'Database=team;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

with open("bike.sql", "r") as file:
    query = file.read()
```

I have attempted to create a function as follows:

```
def get_connection(server:str, Database:str)->str:
    global conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'Server='+server+';'
                      'Database='+Database+';'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    return conn
```

I get the following error:

> global conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the 'global' keyword from your conn variable declaration, then store the output of the function in a new variable.

```
def get_connection(server:str, Database:str)->str:
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                  'Server='+server+';'
                  'Database='+Database+';'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
return conn
```

then call it something like this

```
cn = get_connection("localhost","MyDB")
cn.close()
```

Comment: thx bro, that did the trick